# Creating file with fs then commit makes SVN error 'unexpected end of file'

Tags: node.js, svn, fs

I'm just creating a simple file with `Node.JS` and `fs`

```
 let fs = require('fs');
 fs.writeFileSync('file.txt', '/* CSS */');
```

which works fine. But if I don't open that file and commit it, `SVN` won't commit and reports an error

```
 Unexpected end of index file [path_to_file]/db/revs/0/11 at offset 0x3fe8f
```

If I open that file with `Nodepad++` , add a return carriage and save, `SVN` will be happy.

What is the issue and how do I fix it? Note that since I do not pass any encoding to `writeFileSync`, `utf8` is applied by default.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. What are the exact contents of `file.txt` (I assume that's where "[path_to_file]" points) as shown in an [hexadecimal editor](https://hexed.it/)?

Comment: The content is /* CSS */ : 2F 2A 20 43 53 53 20 2A 2F

Comment: I can't see anything blatantly wrong. Perhaps you're getting some kind of concurrency issues (the file is locked by Node.js or some other tools).

Comment: Just did the test again. Opening and saving in Notepad++ does nothing unless I add a return caret and save, then I won't get end of file error.